# How to stop k6 from failing the CI env when thresholds fail?

Tags: javascript, http, testing, k6

I'm new to [k6](https://k6.io/) and I can't find a way to stop K6 from failing the CI environment when one of the thresholds fail.

I tried the below:

```
thresholds: {
        'http_req_duration{type:firstQuery}': [
            { threshold: 'p(95)>500', abortOnFail: false },
        ],
        'http_req_duration{type:secondQuery}': [
            { threshold: 'p(95)>500', abortOnFail: false },
        ],
    },
```

This didn't work. I need a way to stop K6 default behavior of failing the CI environment when thresholds fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, that this is not k6 failing your CI, but this is CI somehow fails if it get failing result from k6 test scripts. So if you want to disable this behaviour you should investigate your CI configuration, but not k6.

Also 'abortOnFail' flag just rules if k6 test script should abort/stop if threshold fail or should it continue (with failed threshold). And final test result will by failed if some threshold failed (aborted or continued test):

```
ERRO[0007] some thresholds have failed
```

You may have option to remove(or comment) thresholds from you k6 script,
or disable threshold checking with `--no-thresholds` command-line option of k6 run command.

P.S. condition `p(95)>500` seems strange, usually we check for that percentile is less than some value, not more.

Comment: I need to keep thresholds since it's the only way to get average request time for each group in the end of test summary. Also the condition `p(95)>500` is only this way to ensure that tests will pass and won't fail my CI but will show the request time for each group.